# Add option "Open with Ubuntu" in Windows 11 contextual menu

Tags: windows, windows-11, regedit

I'd like to add the option `Open with Ubuntu` in the top level of the contextual menu. Currently the option `Open in Terminal` doesn't work because the path isn't translated into its POSIX form. So I wrote this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Ubuntu]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Ubuntu\command]
@="for /F \"delims=\" %G in ('bash -c \"wslpath -a -u '%V'\"') do cmd.exe /c start wt.exe -p Ubuntu -d \"%G\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Ubuntu\Position]
@="Top"
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: You should start your command by launching a command : `@="cmd.exe /C for /F \"delims`....

Comment: Also try to use this key, without "Background" :  [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Ubuntu]